# Python pandas, how to differentiate between blank and missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample file (to load in dataframe) looks like

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
10,a,111,hzlvkhaslkdvhs
20,b,345,ioadjf ogjdasoivj adoijf 
30,c,
40,d,987,;vjsdf;vm smgv 
50,e,,vbiodhfo vdofhb od
```

Last line has 3rd column blank, which is valid data. Line with col1 == 30 has last few columns missing. If I load this file in dataframe, it treats missing data and blank data in same way

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
>>> df
   col1 col2   col3                       col4
0    10    a  111.0             hzlvkhaslkdvhs
1    20    b  345.0  ioadjf ogjdasoivj adoijf 
2    30    c    NaN                        NaN
3    40    d  987.0            ;vjsdf;vm smgv 
4    50    e    NaN         vbiodhfo vdofhb od
```

How can I distinguish between missing fields and blank fields ?

Comment: Do you want blank represented as empty-string '' and missing represented as NaN? Or else, tell us how you want to 'distinguish' between them? Also called 'implicit NaN' vs 'explicit NaN'

Comment: Technically the way you've provided it the 30 row has only a single missing value, as most logically it should be interepreted as `30,c,*empty_string*NoData` If you expect the last two columns to be "missing" then the line should really be written as `30,c` without the trailing comma.

Comment: Hi smci, I want to make out that in 3rd line there is one less value provided in the file i.e. the line is incomplete. Where as , in last record, its blank values as there are all 4 values/fields present in the file. Basically, I am trying to validate a file if it has all the required fields (they can be empty)